# How to format output console columns in java?

Tags: java, format, invoice

I'm made a program that creates an invoice but when it comes numbers in the thousands the output isn't neat and ruins everything. How do I fix this so the program's columns are more aligned with numbers like this? Here is the code I used to create the program. If anyone could help, it would be much appericated.

Here's the one with the main method...

```
public class InvoicePrinter
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {

  Address samsAddress=new Address("Sam's Small Appliances", "100 Main 
  Street", "Anytown", "CA", "98765");
  Invoice samsInvoice =new Invoice(samsAddress);
  samsInvoice.add(new Product("Toaster", 29.95),3);
  samsInvoice.add(new Product("Hair Dryer", 24.95),1);      
  samsInvoice.add(new Product("Car Vacuum",19.99),2);
  samsInvoice.add(new Product("Nano Parts",100000),1);
  samsInvoice.addSimple(new Product("Shipping",5.00));

  System.out.println(samsInvoice.format());
  }
}
```

These are the other programs needed for the program to work

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Invoice
{
  public Invoice(Address anAddress)
  {
  items=new ArrayList<LineItem>();
  billingAddress=anAddress;
  simpleItems= new ArrayList<SimpleLineItem>();
}

public void addSimple(Product aProduct)
{
  SimpleLineItem anItem= new SimpleLineItem(aProduct);
  simpleItems.add(anItem);
}


public void add(Product aProduct, int quantity)
{
  LineItem anItem=new LineItem(aProduct,quantity);
  items.add(anItem);
}   

 public String format()
 {
  String r="                                                 I N V O I C E\n\n"+billingAddress.format()+String.format("\n\n%-30s%8s%5s%8s\n","Description", "Price","Qty","Total");

  for(LineItem i:items)
  {
     r=r+i.format()+"\n";
  }

  for(SimpleLineItem j:simpleItems)
  {
   r=r+j.format() + "\n";
  }

  r = r + String.format("\nAMOUNT DUE: $%8.2f", getAmountDue());
  return r;
  }

 public double getAmountDue()
 {
  double amountDue = 0;
  for (LineItem i : items)
  {
      amountDue = amountDue + i.getTotalPrice();
  }
  for(SimpleLineItem j:simpleItems)
  {
     amountDue = amountDue + j.getPrice();
  }
 return amountDue; 
  }     


 private Address billingAddress;
 private ArrayList<LineItem> items;
 private ArrayList<SimpleLineItem> simpleItems;
}
```

Few more

```
public class LineItem
{
 public LineItem(Product aProduct, int aQuantity)
 {
  theProduct = aProduct;
  quantity = aQuantity;
 }

 public double getTotalPrice()
 {
  return theProduct.getPrice() *quantity;
 }

 public String format()
 {
  return String.format("%'-30s%'8.2f%'5d%'8.2f", theProduct.getDescription(),theProduct.getPrice(),quantity,getTotalPrice());
 }

 private int quantity;
 private Product theProduct;
}
```

Another one

```
public class SimpleLineItem
{
  public SimpleLineItem(Product aProduct)
  {
     theProduct=aProduct;
  }

  public double getPrice()
  {
     return theProduct.getPrice();   
  }

  public String format()
  {
    return String.format("%-30s" +"             " + "%8.2f",
    theProduct.getDescription(), theProduct.getPrice());
  }

  private Product theProduct;
  }
```

Two more

```
  public class Product
  {  
   public Product(String aDescription,double aPrice)
   {
     description = aDescription;
     price = aPrice;
   }

   public String getDescription()
   {
     return description;
   }

   public double getPrice()
   {
     return price;
   }

   private String description;
   private double price;
   }
```

Last one

```
   public class Address
   {
     public Address(String aName, String aStreet, String aCity, String 
     aState,String aZip)
    {
       name = aName;
       street = aStreet;
       city = aCity;
       state = aState;
       zip = aZip;
    }

   public String format()
   {
     return name + "\n" + street + "\n" + city + ", " + state + " " + zip;
   }

   private String name;
   private String street;
   private String city;
   private String state;
   private String zip;
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried to run your code and throws an exception: Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '''

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take a look at the javadocs by Oracle on System.out.format and DecimalFormat class

[Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Answer (score 0):

So basically this happens when you cannot decide the total length of your number column until you print out everything. For this you will need to set the number column's length to the lengthiest number or in your case price length and justify right all the numbers. So you'll need to add all the numbers to an array and loop through them to find the lengthiest number.

Comment: with like an int array? How do I go about it?

Comment: no you use prices, so get them into a double array. Before you print the entire table, loop through this array and get the highest character length for a number. create necessary indentation to the column values